How high level must a red wizard be to be a red wizard?
For my next campaign, I've decided to run AD&D 1e, and to use the Forgotten Realms campaign setting as it existed in AD&D 1e: 1357 DR, before the Time of Troubles and all the Realms-shaking events that followed it.
Naturally, I want my campaign to include the Forgotten Realm's coolest villains, so I bought myself a copy of Dreams of the Red Wizards and eagerly devoured its contents. For the most part, I was very pleased with my purchase - there's a lot of good stuff in there - but there was one thing I found confusing.
Does every red wizard count as a red wizard? Or do some count as apprentices, and need to earn recognition/gain a certain level before they qualify and gain all the associated privileges and responsibilities?
The book seems to flip back and forth on this issue. Some sections imply that red wizards are high-level: There are only a thousand or so of them in the nation of Thay, every Red Wizard is required to contribute either a circle or a legion to the nation's defence (which is clearly not sustainable if low-level red wizards count, since a circle can only be made of lower-level red wizards), and the section describing red wizards trusted with running enclaves suggests that any magic-user below level 9 is instead an "aspirant to the cloth." However, other sections make reference to lower-level red wizards: The book lists NPC red wizards as low as level 5, and every description of red wizards that focuses on game mechanics is written as if they can be as low as level 1.
I'm not sure what to make of this. Is there an explanation that I've missed of how Red Wizard status is attained, somewhere in the book? Should I assume that "red wizard" is a social rank with little connection to character level? If so, how does a wannabe red wizard achieve it? If the information isn't in this book, was it clarified anywhere else in AD&D 1e, or in 2e? Have I just managed to confuse myself?

You're running AD&D 1E, and tagged it AD&D 2E? Not that important (this is barely tied to mechanics at all), just confusing.

@ShadowRanger Gah, how did I make that mistake? Fixed.

@GMJoe well, at times, 1 or 2 can be confusing. ;) Glad you clarified. Though, do the answers citing 2e materials answer your question. I never played AD&D 1e but I did not assume the rules were interchangeable.

The requirements are partly role-based
To be a Zulkir, they must be "a wizard - a magic-user of 11th level" (Dreams of the Red Wizards, page 25); presumably this really means "at least 11th level". Known Red Wizards outside of Thay are between 9th and 15th level, and can be accompanied by "low-level (1-8) aspirants to the Red Cloth" (DotRW, page 25). But in the very next paragraph, they refer to higher level (9-15) Red Wizards acting so ostentatiously "to cover the activities of the Red Wizards, often of less than 9th level, who act as spies and agents provocateur in the Realms."
Basically, it looks like there are two possible statuses for low-level (below 9th) wizards of Thay:

Aspirants to the Red Cloth - In training and/or supporting a higher-level Red Wizard's circle
Foreign agents - Apparently granted the title of Red Wizard as part of their duties outside Thay, but they operate in secret (that is, not actually wearing the red cloth)

But you can't be the evil-looking, mustache-twirling, red-robed, monologuing villain-style Red Wizard of Thay until you're at least 9th level, and you can't be a Zulkir of one of the schools of magic until you're at least 11th level.

Page n122 of "The Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting" (Grey Box Set) - 2nd Edition

"The Red Wizards roam the lands of Faerun seeking to increase their
power. Any Red Wizard so encountered will not be of less than 9th
level, and may be of up to 15th level. There is a 50% chance of
wandering Red Wizards having bodyguards (usually ogres or other
nonhuman creatures), and an equal chance of them hav¬ ing 1-4
low-level (lst-8th level) aspirants to the red cloth with them."

So, if you are comfortable with moving 2nd edition information into your game, I would say 1st through 8th level wizards are 'aspirants' within the mage circles. The Red Wizards would make a distinction -
but to anyone not part of their group all 'Red Wizards' are 'Red Wizards'.
Also, there are NPCs scattered throughout the books that list 'Red Wizard" in the character information.

Page n170 Red Wizard of Thay NE hf W7


Page n161  Red Wizard of Thay LE hm W5

Which leads to the idea that they can be of any level and still be called 'Red Wizard'. (At least outside of Thay.)

"Thay: Land Of The Red Wizards" is a 5e suppliment written by Ed Greenwood (et. al.) that has the answers you seek. There is a page about how every Thay resident is tested in their early years to see if they have the talent for magic.
There is another chapter that speaks to the training those found to have magical aptitude are given.
There is also a background that speaks to the fact that most Red Wizards do not survive the training.
Source: https://www.drivethrurpg.com/en/product/386190/thay-land-of-the-red-wizards

What are those answers?

This reads more like a comment to the other answer you provided. Could you just merge these together?
